# Upload files to FTP, using .BAT, only once

Tags: batch-file

I have automated file (.doc) uploads to an FTP server through BATCH files.  I then run the BATCH file through the task scheduler every few minutes.

The below two batch files do the work for me:

upload.bat :-

```
open ftp.servername.com
username
password
cd FOLDER_NAME
binary
put D:\TEST\*.doc
bye
```

the above .bat file is called by the below .bat file,

startupload.bat  :-

```
ftp -i -s:upload.bat
```

Now, the client removes files from the FTP once they are uploaded.

So, with above batch files, files are getting repeatedly uploaded.

Hence, my requirement is that each .doc file should be uploaded only once,

(OR,

may be, once a file is successfully uploaded to an FTP, it is shifted to another folder.)

Please help.

Thank you.

Comment: Just as comment: a `batch-file` is a file that contain Batch commands. Your "upload.bat" file is _NOT_ a Batch file, no matters if it have the .bat extension. I suggest you to avoid confusions and change the extension of such a file, for example: `upload.txt`.

Comment: Then put a move command after your ftp command in your batch file.

Answer (score 2):

You can echo the directions into a text file then use -s?

Like the attached image[image]
Then copy them to another folder and delete the originals?

```
@echo off

echo open serveraddress >ftp.txt
echo username>>ftp.txt
echo password>>ftp.txt
echo cd FOLDER_NAME>>ftp.txt
echo binary >>ftp.txt
echo "LCD D:\TEST\"
echo mput *.doc>>ftp.txt
echo bye>>ftp.txt
ftp -s:ftp.txt
del /f /q ftp.txt
copy "D:\TEST\*.doc" "C:\otherFolderPath\"
del /f /q "D:\TEST\*.doc"
::NOTES:
:: you can use ">>" to put the output of a command into a text file.
:: you can use ">" to put the output of a command into a text file. ">" Will clear a file if it exists, and will create a new file if it does not.
```

Note: If you want it to wait some time and then run again you can add this to the end of the script: `Timeout /t 60` (That will wait 60 seconds, or until a user presses a key to continue)

Comment: I'd use a for each loop... don't know what it would look like but for others that do..

Comment: Hi Mark, Thanks for your suggestion. I am not an xpert like you.  Would appreciate if you can update my code.  Thank you.

Comment: There you go :)

Comment: If that does something weird let me know, I might have to change the put command.

Comment: hi Mark, Thanks again. Unfortunately, the issue still remains.

Comment: 1. same file is getting uploaded again and again ( I run bat file thru task scheduler after every 10 mins. A file uploaded first time at 2:10, will get re-uploaded at 2:20, and so on.

2. if the uploaded file is removed from ftp by my client, the same file (sitting in my local folder) gets re-uploaded.

Comment: Try out my edited code. Note that you have to replace `FOLDER_NAME` and `C:\otherFolderPath` with your paths. Hope this one works! Sorry I cant test out the ftp myself